# What is the difference between pip and python2 -m pip?

Tags: python, pip

I was unable to simply `pip install pandas` because my system already had it installed for python3. But I expected that `pip` would attempt to install for python2; `pip3` should install for python3.

Why do I have to specify the python2 interpreter to use `pip`?

```
➜  ~ pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)

➜  ~ python2 -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
Downloading pandas-0.19.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (11.9MB)
...
```

Comment: In your case, default `pip` is of Python 3.5. But when you did `python2 -m pip`, pandas was installed via pip for Python2

Comment: BTW: maybe you have `pip2` or even `pip2.7` and `pip3.5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pip` will call the `pip` that is in the default version of python on your system.  It is not specific to python2.  Since python3 is default on your system you need to specify `python2 -m pip` to access the python2 version.